# VideoReader and VideoWriter on Matlab not getting the same framerate

Tags: matlab, frame-rate

In the original video I get 11 seconds and in the new one 5 seconds. Anyone knows the problem?

```
outputVideo = VideoWriter('openv_v.avi');
open(outputVideo);

vid = VideoReader('openv.avi');

for idx = 1:vid.NumberOfFrames
    img = read(vid, idx);

     writeVideo(outputVideo,img);
end

close(outputVideo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with one line.

```
outputVideo.FrameRate = vid.FrameRate;
```